# php global variable in functions

Tags: php

this is a very simple program, but when i run it, it just out put the first echo statement, which is 3, others are not displaying. i declared it global in the function, why it dose not work, strangely, when i was coding another program declaring a global array variable in a function it works perfectly, please explain it in detail, thanks

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = $a + $b;
echo $c ."<br>";


function aaa()
{

    global $a;
    global $b;

    $d = $a + $b;
    echo $a ."<br>";

function ccc()
{
    global $d;
    $e = $c + 1;
    echo $e;
}

}
```

Comment: Functions don't do anything if you don't call them. You defined functions, but didn't call them in any way.

Comment: It's not a class so don't put ccc functions to inside aaa and where you are calling your functions?

Comment: @Machavity he can.

Comment: PHP has two scopes. global (aka top-level), and local. if you have function definitions/calls nested, you can access any of the intermediate scopes. You need to show the entire code that demonstrations this problem - because the code up top if obviously incomplete: how/where are you calling those functions?

Comment: @Machavity - it simply means that ccc() will never be defined unless aaa() is actually called; but when it is defined, it will still be defined in the global namespace [Demo](https://3v4l.org/8sDeH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you've put the function ccc inside the funciton aaa and that is not the correct way of doing what you're trying to do.
The correct way would be to create a `Class aaa` and then declaring `ccc as its method`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = $a + $b;
$d = 0;

function aaa() {
  global $a;
  global $b;
  global $d;

  $d = $a + $b;
  echo $a ."<br>";
}

function ccc() {
  global $c;
  global $d;
  $e = $c + 1;
  echo $e;
}

echo $c ."<br>";
aaa();
ccc();
```

Comment: @AdamKonieska Fixed. Thanks for spotting.